# jQuery- Hide table -> After reloading page,my table shows up for couple seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have problem with my table.I use jQuery function `.hide()`.

```
 $("#table").hide();
```

And that works perfectly, but there is one problem.After reloading page, my table shows up for couple seconds and then hide.
I have been trying many things, i put .hide() function first in list but still nothing.

I used `$("#table").css("display", "none")`, but still i have same problem.

What should i do?

Comment: Can you provide us with a quick jfiddle please? Will be easier to help :)

Comment: Better style `<table>`'s display on markup, as if you put the code before table render, `js` can't get table, but if you put it after table markup, table should show before it's hide.

Comment: Sounds like it should be easily fixable. But can you provide a [minimal, complete code sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question where we can look at? Something which can be run in, for example, jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like,

Add style to table For Example,

```
<table id="table" style="display: none">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Thiru</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I am new here so i cant give you a positive feedback.Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use jQuery to hide content on load, just use display: none.

```
#table {
  display: none;
}
```

To answer to your question, I you are using hide() into a $(document).ready(function() {}). So it is executed after your page is fully loaded.